# Is it possible to utilize pandas' data structures from a python c extension function?

Tags: python, c, module, pandas

I wrote a Python extension module in C. I return PyListObject on some functions.

Is it possible to instead accept pandas' data structures as arguments and return them?

Series or DataFrame for example.

Comment: you could, but they would just be a ``PyObject``. Better to pass the actual data (the underlying numpy array) as you normally would operate on. However, before I did anything I would profile and see if all this work is even necessary.

Comment: worth checking out cython for this kind of stuff (if it really is necessary)

Comment: Thanks for the help. But ideally I would want to write the code all in C (because my existing module has already been written in C and it interacts with an underlying C API). If a Series or DataFrame was passed to a C function is there an API for dealing with those objects. Something comparable to the API for List: http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/list.html